# Connecting usb switch using usb a to c cable

Tags: usb, usb-c

I am trying to connect a usb switch([Amazon link](https://www.amazon.nl/dp/B01N6GD9JO?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)) that uses usb a ports to my laptop using a usb a - c cable. Connecting it directly using this cable does not work, however, when I connect it indirectly via a usb c hub (using the same usb c - a cable) it does work.

The other port of the switch is plugged into my desktop, and when I unplug this the switch seems to not get any power, no matter if I attach it directly or via a usb c hub. This leads me to believe it might be some sort of usb negotiation issue but I am not sure how I can troubleshoot this, or if this is even possible.

I have tried different operating systems and different devices(phones and laptops) and all of them have the same issue.

Comment: This reads as a report, not a question. Also, a photo of the situation may help, I have trouble following what exactly sticks into what.

Comment: Which end of the C-A cable are you connecting to the switch, and which end are you connecting to the computer? If you're connecting type-A to the computer, are you connecting it to a USB3 port or a USB2 port?

Comment: @user1686 I am connecting the usb c end to the laptop and the usb a end to the switch. The computer is connected via usb a - a 3.0. The usb c - a cable is also 3.0